# Terms for "stuff" preceeding and following an item in a sequence

Tags: word-choice, terminology, programming

I need insight from a native speaker of any variety of English on what to call items in a sequence that proceeds or follows a certain item.

In a sequence "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11",  I want to focus on 7 and then include, say three items preceding the 7 and 2 items following, so that I get a new sequence "4 5 6 **7** 8 9".

But what do you call the part before and after the **7**? Pre/postamble? lead in / (what?)? What would you call something that proceeds or follows the center?
I thought about "onset" and "coda" but in phonetics these are already burdened terms that would lead the thinking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Are you talking specifically about numbers in a sequence, or other types of list, or other contexts? Are you looking for a technical, programming term rather than something ordinary people will understand? (I think there are lots of candidate words, but they often don't form neat pairs, and to find the best ones more information is needed.)

Comment: I think your '[the] three [elements] preceding the '7', ['7' itself], and [the] two items following' is as concise as it gets, Fredrik.

Comment: Thank you. What I am attempting do to is to make programming function arguments (@EdwinAshworth, which is why the full sentence description does not work) that users with potentially very little programming background should understand as easily as possible. What they want to achieve is to able to zoom into just a part of a timeline and extract measurements in a time series there, and a specified number of measurements before and after.

Comment: In maths, one would use 'for x = 4-9' or x∈ℕ: 4 ≤ x ≤ 9.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for that, but I was looking for English language terms, if there are some, that makes it clear that a function argument refers to "n items before" and "n items after" a given reference item. Like "preamble_length". Or "onset length" if it would always refer to a syllable, but that term seems exclusively used for syllable descriptions.

Comment: I am trying to avoid argument names simular to "before=?" and "after=?" as they are not clearly understood without reading further (is the reference before or after something?), and "n_before" also takes some thinking to convince yourself that you have understood it correctly. Would a native speaker / reader react violently if I used "preamble" and "postamble" for these things? Lat. Praeambulous "walking in front" seems about right to me, but then again I am not a native speaker.

Comment: I don't understand why the question was closed, it looks fine to me. Grep uses the word **context** for the [_non-matching lines that are near a matching line_](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Context-Line-Control.html), and I've found it's easy to remember and explain to other people.